# Renaming Multiple Layers after using split vector tool

Tags: qgis, layers, vector-layer

I am using the split vector layer tool and then adding the vector layers. These are currently getting named as by the Field ID_the unquie value. So for example Box_12, Box_13, Box_18. Obviously when I add these newly created layers they are named as such Box_12, Box_13, Box_18. I was wondering if there was a way to remove the Field ID_ on all layers so I would just have layers named 12, 13,18?